# Clicking on checkbox based on tables column value - IE Webdriver Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, xpath-2.0

Clicking on checkbox based on tables column value using Xpath. Below is the html

```
  <table id="tblHotels"> 
  <TBODY> 
    <TR> 
      <TH align="left"> 
        <INPUT checkbox="" id="chkNSelectAll  name=chkNSelectAll  type="/> 
      </TH>  
      <TH align="left" title="Hotel">Hotel</TH>  
      <TH title=" align=left"> 
        <SPAN id="spnExpandBtn">
          <IMG/>
        </SPAN> 
      </TH>  
      <TH align="left" title="Hotel">Hotel</TH>  
      <TH align="left" title="Reg Date">Reg Date</TH>  
      <TH align="left" title="Room Type">Room Type</TH>  
      <TH align="left" title="Location">Location</TH>  
      <TH align="left" title="Room Number">Room Number</TH> 
    </TR>  
    <TR> 
      <TD colSpan="11"> 
        <IMG src=" ../NoExpiry/images/uaimBSpacer.gif"/> 
      </TD> 
    </TR>  
    <TR> 
      <TD> 
        <INPUT id="chkNSelect" name="chkNSelect" type="checkbox" value="on"/> 
      </TD>  
      <TD customHiddenText="">MATHEW Joe</TD>  
      <TD/>  
      <TD customHiddenText=""> 
        <SPAN>Affray (
          <STRONG/>Kim Lee)
        </SPAN> 
      </TD>  
      <TD class="regDate customHiddenText=">10/01/2014</TD>  
      <TD customHiddenText="">1HE</TD>  
      <TD customHiddenText="">South West </TD>  
      <TD id="tdChildroom name=" tdChildroom=""/>  
      <INPUT id="hidYID" name="hidYID" type="hidden" value="409"> 
        <INPUT id="hidYD" name="hidYD" type="hidden"> 
          <INPUT id="hidYDID" name="hidYDID" type="hidden" value="1015389"/> 
        </INPUT> 
      </INPUT> 
    </TR>  
    <TR> 
      <TD> 
        <INPUT id="chkNSelect" name="chkNSelect" type="checkbox" value="on"/> 
      </TD>  
      <TD customHiddenText="">MATHEW Penny</TD>  
      <TD/>  
      <TD customHiddenText=""> 
        <SPAN>Affray (
          <STRONG/>Jim Lee)
        </SPAN> 
      </TD>  
      <TD class="regDate customHiddenText=">10/01/2014</TD>  
      <TD customHiddenText="">1HE</TD>  
      <TD customHiddenText="">South West </TD>  
      <TD id="tdChildroom name=" tdChildroom=""/>  
      <INPUT id="hidYID" name="hidYID" type="hidden" value="409"> 
        <INPUT id="hidYD" name="hidYD" type="hidden"> 
          <INPUT id="hidYDID" name="hidYDID" type="hidden" value="1015389"/> 
        </INPUT> 
      </INPUT> 
    </TR> 
  </TBODY> 
</table>
```

here is what i am trying and this always clicks the first checkbox??

```
Driver.FindElementByXPath("//td[contains(text(),'MATHEW Penny')]/preceding::td/input[@name='chkNSelect']").Click()
```

If i try to just find the column with the text it can find it not why it cannot find the preceding check box and jumps to first rows check box??

```
 Driver.FindElementByXPath("//td[contains(text(),'MATHEW Penny')]
```

my requirement is to select the first checkbox (do something eg:add it to another table) uncheck it then check the 2nd checkbox (do something eg:add it to another table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use for MATHEW Penny:

```
//td[contains(text(),'Penny')]/preceding-sibling::td/input[@name='chkNSelect']
```

Use for MATHEW Joe:

```
//td[contains(text(),'Joe')]/preceding-sibling::td/input[@name='chkNSelect']
```

Comment: fab! preceding-sibling:: has done the magic :) so it still works with Mathew in it Driver.FindElementByXPath("//td[contains(text(),'MATHEW Penny')]/preceding-sibling::td/input[@name='chkNSelect']").Click()

Answer (score 0):

Its selecting all `input` elements with `name` as `chkNSelect` which comes before `td` with text as `MATHEW Penny`.
Use

```
//td[contains(text(),'MATHEW Penny')]/preceding::td/input[last()][@name='chkNSelect']
```

to select only first such input

Comment: That didn't help either it is always selecting the first checkbox :( I tried to use tr that doesn't check any boxes Driver.FindElementByXPath("//tr[td[contains(text(),'MATHEW Penny')]/preceding::td/input[@name='chkNSelect']]").Click()

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

- first targeting the `tr`
- containing the `td` with the text node you want (using a predicate)
- and then going to an `input` within a `td` in that table row

So that translates to:

```
Driver.FindElementByXPath("//tr[td[contains(text(),'MATHEW Penny')]]/td/input[@name='chkNSelect']")
```

Breakdown:

```
//tr[
        td[
              contains(text(),'MATHEW Penny')
          ]
    ]
    /td/input[@name='chkNSelect']
```

Comment: where is the close bracket ']'of tr?

Comment: I added a breakdown view of the XPath

Comment: Driver.FindElementByXPath("//tr[td[contains(text(),'MATHEW Joe')]]/td/input[@name='chkNSelect']").Click() It works once just ticks it second time it throws error FindElementByXPath' is not a member of 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver